# DB Aggregation and BI Best Practices

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse, aggregation, business-intelligence, query-performance

We have a fair amount of aggregating queries in our db for use on making (sometimes real-time) business decisions.  Unfortunately the pages that present these aggregates are some of the most frequently called, and the SPs are passed parameters by the page.  The queries themselves have been tuned, but Unfortunately each SP is generation a handful of aggregate fields.

We're working on some performance tuning, and one of the tasks is to re-work how/where these aggregations are done.

The thoughts we have are to possibly create SPs that do some of these and store them in a table.  Then the page could run a more simple select query on the table still using a parameter to limit it to the correct data-set.  It wouldn't be as "real time", but could be frequently enough.

The other suggested solution was to perform the aggregation queries in our DWH and (through) SSIS pass the data back to a table in the Prod db.  There is significantly less traffic on our DWH db, so it could easily handle the heavy lifting.

What are the thoughts on ways to streamline querying and presenting what would typically be considered "reporting" data in a Prod environment?  The current SPs are called probably a couple thousand times a day.  Is pushing DWH data back to a Prod db against BI best practices?  Is this something better done in a CLR Proc (not that familiar with CLR)?

Comment: SSIS isn't a great fit for real-time work. What version and edition of SQL Server are you working with? `SELECT 
    SERVERPROPERTY('productversion') AS ProductVersion
,   SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel') AS ProductLevel
,   SERVERPROPERTY ('edition') AS Edition;`

Comment: The other question when dealing with real-time questions, is do they really need real-time or can "near real time" where NRT is up to N timeunits delayed. Can you constrain these aggregations to certain routes (we always aggregate sales by quarter) or is it (users can aggregate any value by any measure)?

Comment: We're on 2008 R2, moving to 2012 by EoY.  Some stuff definitely needs to be RT while other stuff can be NRT.  There are people working a queue, and determine who to assign stuff to based on the aggregate data for the people eligible to receive the work in the queue.

Comment: Pity you weren't going to 2014. 2012 introduced the Columnstore index, which is a wicked cool thing that allows for crazy aggregation performance (since the data is stored as a column, instead of a row, it can easily run calcs on it). The problem with it as a solution for 2012 is that it's read only. 2014 allows for updateable CSI. There are approaches, mind you. If say your data is only ever increasing, you can slap a view on top of the historical data stored with a CSI and 24 hours is in a "live" table and then nightly migrate and rebuild the CSI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make use of pre-aggregated calculations and still answer all questions in NRT, this is what you could do:

Calculate an aggregate every minute/hour/day and store this in the database as an aggregated value. Then, if a query is done on the database you use these aggregates. For the time that isn't in the aggregate, you use the raw data that was inserted after the final timestamp of the last aggregate. It requires a bit more coding, but this is the ultimate solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem with pushing aggregate reporting data back to a prod DB from a data warehouse for delivery, but as a commenter mentioned, you would inherently introduce a delay which might not be acceptable for your 'real-time' decisions.

Another option, as long as the nature of your aggregation is relatively straightforward, is indexed views. Essentially you create a view of the source table with the level of aggregation required for reporting, and then put an index on it. The index means that SQL server actually precalculates the view and stores it on disk like a real table, so that when you do a reporting query, it doesn't actually need to read the full detail of the source table and aggregate it.

Another neat trick that SQL can do with indexed views is 'aggregate awareness', which means that even if you query the source table, if the planner realises it can get the answer from the indexed view more quickly, then it will. You wouldn't even need to update your existing procs for them to gain a benefit.

It probably sounds too good to be true, and in some ways it is, since there are are couple of massive downsides:

- There are a large number of limitations on the SQL syntax you can use in the view, for example while you can use sum and count_big, you can't use max/min (which seems odd to be honest). You can do inner but not outer joins. You can't use window functions. The list goes on...
- Also, there will obviously be a performance cost when writing to the tables the view references, as the view has to be updated. So you would want to test out performance in your environment with a typical workload before you turn something like this on in prod.